# Only retrieve specific data from a row in DynamoDB using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Using DynamoDb and the "read" function provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.02) how would I go about only retrieving specific items (e.g. only firstname, lastname and city)
I would probably have to add some kind of filter, however i was not able to find anything that I could use.

This is my table structure (with bpNumber being the primary key):

```
Item:{
            "salutationCode": "02",
            "lastName1": "Berg",
            "firstName": "Anne",
            "street": "Am Dächle",
            "streetNumber": "22/2",
            "zipcode": "33425",
            "countryCode": "DE",
            "city": "Hausen",
            "bpNumber": 222,
            "dateOfBirth": "1955-07-01",
            "attri": [
              {
                "attri1":"nonono"
              },
              {
                "attri2": "yeayeayea"
              }
            ]

        }
```

and this the "read" method I'm using:

```
read(){
        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

        var table = "businessPartnersData";

        var bpNumber = 222;

        var params = {
            TableName: table,
            Key:{
                "bpNumber": bpNumber
            }
        };

        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        });
  }
```

Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use ProjectionExpression:

```
params.ProjectionExpression = "firstname, lastname, city";
```

This will only return these attributes in the resultset, for all items.

Comment: awesome, thank you. Probably shoud've found this on my own.